# Tensorflow: List of available **kwargs

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In Tensorflow API documents, I have difficulty to find all available keyword arguments.

For example, ["GlobalMaxPooling1D"](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GlobalMaxPool1D) layer in Tensorflow API:

```py
tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool1D(
    data_format='channels_last', **kwargs
)
```

I am curious to know where to find the information on all available keyword arguments (**kwargs).

Or is there any way to list all available keyword arguments from a built-in function or a built-in command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of `tf.keras.layers.Layer` subclasses, like `GlobalMaxPooling1D`, [valid keyword arguments](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/fcc4b966f1265f466e82617020af93670141b009/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L308-L316) are

```
allowed_kwargs = {
    'input_dim',
    'input_shape',
    'batch_input_shape',
    'batch_size',
    'weights',
    'activity_regularizer',
    'autocast',
}
```

In the `__init__` of `Layer` subclasses, you will see a call like `super().__init__(**kwargs)`, which passes the keyword arguments you enter to the initializer of the base `Layer` class.

[For example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/fcc4b966f1265f466e82617020af93670141b009/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/pooling.py#L713-L716):

```
class GlobalPooling1D(Layer):
  """Abstract class for different global pooling 1D layers."""


  def __init__(self, data_format='channels_last', **kwargs):
    super(GlobalPooling1D, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.input_spec = InputSpec(ndim=3)
    self.data_format = conv_utils.normalize_data_format(data_format)
```

Comment: When we do subclassing, can you please explain why we have to pass `**kwargs` to `super().__init__(**kwargs)` in the `__init__` function of our subclass model of `Model` class?